Bold-italic is not being converted properly from HTML to DOC conversion
Here is the content of the HTML-file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 plus MathML 2.0//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/xhtml-math11-f.dtd" > 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<!-- xhtml,mathml,mathml-,html --> 
<meta name="src" content="test.tex" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" /> 
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 7--><p class="noindent" ><!--l. 7--><math 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"  
display="inline" ><mstyle mathvariant="bold-italic"><mi 
>x</mi></mstyle><mi 
>T</mi><mstyle mathvariant="bold-italic"><mi 
>&#x03B1;</mi></mstyle><mover 
accent="true"><mrow 
><mstyle mathvariant="bold-italic"><mi 
>&#x03C6;</mi></mstyle></mrow><mo accent="true">^</mo></mover></math>
</p><!--l. 9--><p class="indent" >   <!--l. 9--><math 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"  
display="inline" ><mi 
>x</mi><mi 
>T</mi><mi 
>&#x03B1;</mi></math>
</p>
    
</body></html>

And have converted to DOC format using the command:
pandoc -s test.html --mathml -o test.docx

Bold and italic characters are converted only to the bold font. How can I make them bold and italic in the doc-file?
